# Javascript function doesn't get called - ASP.NET and UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

I have the following structure on a usercontrol that is loaded by a page (Parent UC):

```
<UpdatePanel>
  <UpdatePanel>
     .. In the codebehind, it loads a Child user control at runtime
  </UpdatePanel>
</UpdatePanel>
```

The UC has OnPageLoad registers a script.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "Load_" + this.ClientID, base.GetRegisterScript(this.ClientID), true);
```

The JS function never gets executed on async postbacks. If i remove the UpdatePanels, it works as expected

**EDIT: Used this.GetType() instead of typeof(Page) but no luck**

**EDIT Again:**

Matt - I tried to replace the typeof(Page) with the UC name. Here's the updated line:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(TemplateAreaTypeOne), "Load_" + this.ClientID, "...JS function here,,", true);
```

To clarify, the Page loads the Parent UC that has these UpdatePanels. The ParentUC then loads the ChildUC and the ScriptManager.RegisterStartuScript is used in teh ChildUC

EDIT

The markup has:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
; findControl('PageLoadedHiddenTxtBox').value ='Set';OnLoadBegin('ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_ctlUnion1_ctlUnion1Child','Edit');OnLoadEnd('ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_ctlUnion1_ctlUnion1Child','Edit');
document.getElementById('ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_informationSummary').dispose = function() {
    Array.remove(Page_ValidationSummaries, document.getElementById('ctl00_WorkSpaceContent_informationSummary'));
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Note that the functions that are called are the OnLoadBegin and OnLoadEnd that have been added to the HTML

EDIT AGAIN

Got it to work using:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page),....)
```

Not sure why it works when I use the reference to the Page.

1. Will this work if I have multiple controls on the Page?
2. Why does it work when I use a reference to the page?

Comment: Can you add the entire code of your update panel?

Comment: you need to control type not the type of this, whatever the control is that you are targetting you need that type registered for the startup script, so if you are loading a control MyControl then typeof(MyControl) the startupscript has to know what to target in the partial postback

Comment: i think you may have other problems here due to adding the control from codebehind, scriptmanager registers the scripts after the main markup has been parsed, so you can't use <% %> type replacements within the js that is added this way, id like to rule out the control type first though

Comment: ok, so can you check that your script is in the markup, stick an alert('hello') in there to make sure it is running, also you are calling a "js function here" is that in the markup or is it added using registerClientScriptBlock, and if so where ?

Comment: Yes, the JS is in the markup. I have edited my original post with the markup

Comment: rather than calling the methods can you just add an alert to the startupscript, to make sure its being run, im still not sure that it is from what i can see, so rather than js function here just stick a dirty alert in there. ive had plenty of pain with the way scriptmanager works,call it war wounds

Comment: ya, did that as well. No luck with a simple alert('yo'); 

Note: The UpdatePanels are in ParentControl. Could that be making this more difficult than it should be? My gut says I need to figure out the first 2 params of the registerstartupscript correctly.

Comment: yes, its the usual source of the problem, i dont think it helps that the  control is added in codebehind, at what part of the lifecycle are the controls added ?

Comment: is there any way you can get a limited version of the source available to have look at?

Comment: I finally got it to work by using the code in the post (edited)

I got it by trying different combinations. I am not sure I understand the logic of using the Page as the reference and not the control.

Comment: can you check if this works after the first page load, the key with registerstartupscript with the scriptmanager is, it knows to "prime" the startup script AND run it after a partial postback, that way it will make sure that handlers etc are hooked up after each partial postback, im looking at it.

Comment: Matt - yes it runs. Not sure why though

Comment: ive had a look in reflector, and it will actually work like this which surprises me (ive never looked at the code before now) the only thing it really needs is the first attribute, it uses this to find an active script manager, if you pass a control here, the code looks for a page anywa

Answer (score 2):

your registerstartupscript needs to target the control NOT the page dont use typeof(Page)